# Create stacked bar chart with a single dataset per stack

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Say I have the following data points:

```js
let points = [
    {key: "foo", value: 1},
    {key: "foo", value: 2},
    {key: "foo", value: 1},
    {key: "bar", value: 2},
    {key: "bar", value: 1}
];
```

I would like to create a chart that looks similar to the following:

```
  5 +-------------------------------+
    |                               |
  4 |      +-----+                  |
    |      |     |                  |
  3 |      +-----+      +-----+     |
    |      |     |      |     |     |
  2 |      |     |      +-----+     |
    |      |     |      |     |     |
  1 |      +-----+      |     |     |
    |      |     |      |     |     |
  0 +------+-----+------+-----+-----+
             foo          bar
```

The actual dataset has many different stacks, I have simplified it for this example. I have been able to accomplish the effect with the following, but every point is treated as its own dataset and I feel like there should be a cleaner and more efficient solution:

```
let datasets = [
    {label: "foo", stack: "foo", data: [1]},
    {label: "foo", stack: "foo", data: [2]},
    {label: "foo", stack: "foo", data: [1]},
    {label: "bar", stack: "bar", data: [2]},
    {label: "bar", stack: "bar", data: [1]}
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values of each dataset are distributed to the various stacked bars. Therefore, the required number of datasets corresponds to the maximum number of values that can be contained in a stacked bar.

Accordingly, for your example you need the following three datasets:

```
[1, 2]
[2, 1]
[1, 0]
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Stacked Bar Chart</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        canvas {
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width: 75%">
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script>
        var data = {
            labels: ['foo', 'bar'],
            datasets: [{
                backgroundColor: 'red',
                data: [1, 2]
            }, {
                backgroundColor: 'green',
                data: [2, 1]
            }, {
                backgroundColor: 'blue',
                data: [1, 0]
            }]
        };
        window.onload = function() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
            window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: data,
                options: {
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Stacked Bar Chart'
                    },
                    tooltips: {
                        mode: 'index',
                        intersect: false
                    },
                    legend: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    responsive: true,
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            stacked: true,
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                            stacked: true
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
        };
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So I would have to go across all of my objects, find out what the largest stack is, and then distribute them properly in an array so they were all the same height (with a 0 where it is not present in the stack). That's what I was afraid of, I was hoping for the ability to give each stack as a dataset. Thank you!