# Chart.js dynamic dataset and tooltip on stacked bar

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I want to create a stacked bar chart.

I saw [sample](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/bar/stacked.html) and [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html) from chart.js but i didn't find example using dynamic dataset and tooltip.

What i want to achieve is like a picture below.

[image]

So the first stacked bar is consisted of two datasheet; 15 and 30, sum to 45.
When user hovering this first stacked bar it will show tooltip; "15 (1-3)" for bottom bar and "30 (3-6)" for hovering top bar. The problem is i don't know how to attach dynamic dataset (for one single date it will contain 1 to 10 datasets) and show the corresponding tooltip. I can generate line/bar chart with dynamic datasets but stacked bar is new for me.

My json data source is like this:

```
[
   {
      "date":"2020-02-07",
      "range":"1-3",
      "off":15
   },
   {
      "date":"2020-02-07",
      "range":"3-6",
      "off":30
   },
   {
      "date":"2020-02-08",
      "range":"1-4",
      "off":25
   },
   {
      "date":"2020-02-08",
      "range":"4-5",
      "off":15
   },
   {
      "date":"2020-02-08",
      "range":"5-6",
      "off":15
   }
]
```

It should genereate the following stacked bar.

[image]

Could you provide me some examples or maybe i miss some part in documentation that already show what i want?

Thank you.

Comment: did you try any ways ??

Comment: @AashifAhamed Yeah, i tried the sample on chart.js web. They only show data with same fixed dataset (dataset 1, dataset 2, dataset 3) the label show when hovering is the data itself (ex: 15) but i also want to show "15 (1-3)". If this take too much work than i will find another solution like show modal when hovering bar chart and show the detail there.

Comment: please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45122306/vertical-stacked-bar-chart-with-chart-js

Comment: @AashifAhamed Thank you. I have take a look on that. So i need to play with zero value to make the dataset dynamic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/59658062/2358409 to understand how it basically works.

Starting from this information, some data processing together with the use of [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/) leads you to the following sample code.

```js
const data = [
   {
      "date":"2020-02-07",
      "range":"1-3",
      "off":15
   },
   {
      "date":"2020-02-07",
      "range":"3-6",
      "off":30
   },
   {
      "date":"2020-02-08",
      "range":"1-4",
      "off":25
   },
   {
      "date":"2020-02-08",
      "range":"4-5",
      "off":15
   },
   {
      "date":"2020-02-08",
      "range":"5-6",
      "off":15
   }
];

const distinctDates = Array.from(new Set(data.map(o => o.date)));
const dataPerDate = distinctDates.map(d => data.filter(o => o.date == d));
const numberOfDatasets = Math.max.apply(null, dataPerDate.map(data => data.length));
const dataSets = [];
for (let i = 0; i < numberOfDatasets; i++) {
  dataSets.push({
    data: dataPerDate.map(data => i < data.length ? data[i].off : 0),
    ranges: dataPerDate.map(data => i < data.length ? data[i].range : ''),
    backgroundColor: distinctDates.map(d => 
      "rgba(" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + "," + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + "," + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ", 0.5)"),
    categoryPercentage: 1,
    barPercentage: 1
  }); 
}

new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: distinctDates,
    datasets: dataSets
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
   datalabels: {
        display: context => context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex] > 0,
        formatter: (value, context) => value + ' (' + context.dataset.ranges[context.dataIndex] + ')'
   }
  },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
         stacked: true
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }]      
    }
  }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  max-width: 300px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```